# Count only rows that start with.... (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame where I would like to count only rows that start with R34_ and their column x == 3.

```
              x
R34_sdasdsa   3
R34_sdasdsa   3
R36_sdasdsa   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `R34_` are actually the rownames of your dataframe (let's call it `df`) and that you have other columns in addition to `x`, you can subset the dataframe using square brackets and then count the rows using `nrow()`

```
new_df <- df[(startsWith(rownames(df), "R34_")) & (df$x == 3), ]
nrow(new_df)
# [1] 2
```

---

Otherwise, if `x` is the only column of your dataframe, the above result will bring you `NULL` because the subset operation will return a vector instead of a dataframe. In this case, you should try `length()`

```
length(df[(startsWith(rownames(df), "R34_")) & (df$x == 3), ])
# [1] 2
```